# I've deleted the boot partitions on my hard disk drive. Data still remains. Can I recover it or make the system bootable?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot-partition, bootrepair

Using a cloning tool to move my hard disk drive’s data to another drive, I saw some weird, unnamed partitions that I thought were unnecessary and/or malware... And very confidently, proceeded to erase them. Now my computer won't boot.

Because at the moment I thought it wasn't supposed to be there, I didn't pay a lot of attention to what the partitions names were, they were about 4 or 5 of them.

I know my information is safe, so I have that going for me at least; I just don't know how to fix this ridiculous mess that I've gotten myself into.

The only two partitions remaining are the main `C:` and the default recovery partition.

Comment: Edit your questions and indicate which partitions you deleted exactly.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have probably put yourself in an unrecoverable state.  Without knowing what partitions were there before, it's very unlikely to be able to get it working again.  It's possible that your data might still be in the remaining partitions in a state you can access using a Ubuntu LiveCD or similar.  If you boot into one of those, you might be able to copy your files to an external disk.

Comment: If the answer provided below doesn't fix your predicament, you may be able to use that same disk cloning app to move the data in your C: drive to an external storage device, use a Windows installation disk to delete all the partitions, reinstall Windows, then clone the data in C: back to your disk. I have been in similar situations before, and thankfully had a full image backup from which to restore my mistake. And FWIW, you should have at least 4 partitions: EFI, MSR (Microsoft Reserved), data/system, and WRE (Windows Recovery).

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly recover the drive by using BOOTREC. You will need a bootable Windows install disk or flash drive.

- Once booted into the Windows installation click "OK" or whatever the button is to go to the next screen
- Click "Repair computer" or similar. This option will be in the bottom left of the pop up installation window.
- Click "Advanced options"
- Click "Command Prompt"

No we should see out Command Prompt window come up, so we can get into the possible recovery.

*Type all of these commands without the quotations. The quotations are to define the command*

- Type "Bootrec.exe /ScanOS", hit Enter
- Type "Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd", hit Enter
- Type "Bootrec.exe /FixMBR", hit Enter
- Type "Bootrec.exe /FixBoot", hit Enter

Hopefully this works for you! I've done the same in my early Windows OS days.